# Having trouble outputing a re.search and re.match in a while loop

Tags: python, regex, search, match, regex-group

I am trying to print and ultimately write info and Data to a file with python. I read in a file to an array called `List[]` and then search each line with a regular expression. I want to do this for every line in a file but when I do this

```
counter=0
while counter <= OrderNum:    
    Info=re.match('^.{0,12}',List[counter])
    Data=re.search('=....................',List[counter])
    print counter
    print 'is less than'
    print OrderNum
    print Info.group(counter)
    print Data.group(counter)
    counter+=1
```

Everything is fine for the first iteration [0] but once

```
Output
1
is less than 
4
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\*******\workspace\Jython\regularexpressions.py", line 35, in <module>
print Info.group(counter)
IndexError: no such group
```

Comment: try Info.group(0) / Data.group(0) instead of .group(counter)

Answer (score 2):

`match.group(n)` returns regex group `n` (or the whole match if n=0). A group in regex is something inside parentesis and you get the exception since you don't have any groups in your expression. Show us the data you are trying to match and we'll help you with a better expression.

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` and `re.search` return [`Match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) objects. If you don't pass a parameter to the `.group` method, you get the whole match.

If you are trying to create some lists from another list, you should do something like this.

```
info_list = []
data_list = []

for counter, item in enumerate(the_list):    
    info=re.match('^.{0,12}', item)
    data=re.search('=....................', item)
    info_list.append(info.group())
    data_list.append(data.group())
```

I've changed some of your variable names to be more compliant with [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's a good idea to make your code easy to read for other Python developers.